# Calculating A Transformer Core Power Capability

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, magnetics, core

I'm trying to build a transformer for a full bridge dc-dc converter and it's my very first time to design a transformer and I got limited knowledge.

I'm checking some ferrite cores and I've found this: 
https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/80/db/fer/e_55_28_21.pdf

But I can't figure out it's power limits from datasheet, so how can I calculate this?

(planning to use this core in EE configuration, without a gap, in 30kHz, output is slightly higher than 2kW)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but isn't that a bit too high of a requirement to go on without knowing about it?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen it's a must for me, so I'm working on it.

Comment: How many turns of the correct amp rating can you fit in. Explain input and output voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka input is 40Vmin, 48Vnominal, 60Vmax, output is 350V at 2kW

Comment: And...............

Comment: What do you need to learn before you can design your own transformer? https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/en/180490/design-support/design-tools/ferrite-magnetic-design-tool

Comment: https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/en/529404/products/product-catalog/ferrites-and-accessories/epcos-ferrites-and-accessories/ferrite-materials  <Maybe you should reverse engineer designs 1st then look here

Comment: If this is going into production, just contact one of the major magnetics vendors, give them your specs and ask them to propose a design for you.  If not, you have a lot of learning to do and probably a bunch of iterations before you get a workable design.